# Android live rendering strip chart library

Tags: android, charts, data-acquisition, stripchart

I am trying to find the best charting library for my android app that receives live data from a data acquisition device (supports up to 800 samples per sec). I need to display a live, moving strip chart with some additional features like zooming in and out and tracing back the chart. I have looked at a few open source libraries like `achartengine` , `afreechart`, `graphView` but can't really seem to decide which one I should go with due to lack of enough examples and information. Any helpful links? Any recommendation?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you try AChartEngine for your project. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828616/can-any-one-suggest-me-some-good-tutorials-on-achartengine-for-android-developme) for some tutorials.

There is also another related [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424752/any-good-graphing-packages-for-android) on this.

Comment: Decided to go with `GraphView` since I will be dealing with just line graphs. Thanks.